# Extract all numbers from a string along with their signs - Python 2.7

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

How do I extract all numbers along with sign?

Strings can be like these
`-1+110`, `+20-123` and `+23-432-543`

I am using this simple regular expression

```
event_book_value = re.findall('\d+', event_book_value)
```

it returns the numbers but do not return along with signs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add an optional sign in front of the number regex:

```
[+-]?\d+
```

- `[+-]` - a [character set](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) that matches a single `+` or `-`
- `?` - makes the previous match one or zero times
- `\d+` - one or more digits

[See it in action](https://repl.it/BgZr/0)

Comment: thanks. it works. can you pls show more examples of `?` sign ... how it really works ... little confused about that

Comment: @Umair, I put the `?` just so that you will still match if there is a number without a sign. It basically makes the previous thing optional. In other words - `xy?z` will match either `xyz` or `xz`.

Answer (score 1):

something like this:

```
def signSplit(string):
    nums = []
    cur = ""
    signs = "+-"
    for c in string:
        if c in signs:
            if cur:#if there is a number (so not the very beginning) then add it to nums
                nums.append(cur)
            cur = c #start out with the cur storing the sign
        elif c.isdigit():
            cur+=c
        else:
            raise ValueError("unrecognised character: %r"%c)
    nums.append(cur)
    return nums


print(signSplit("+23-432-543"))
```

It may be too slow for your needs but it works in pure python so easy to make edits later.

Comment: thanks for effort but this is very lengthy and slow solution :(

Comment: personally I frequently have to deal with small amounts of data that never follow the same rules twice so versatile and verbose code is right up my alley, glad you got the answer you were looking for and glad to offer an alternative. :)